# Computing row sums of a big.matrix in R?

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I have a big matrix with about 60 million rows and 150 colums (roughly 9 billion elements total). I have stored this data in a `big.matrix` object (from package `bigmemory`). Now, I wish to compute the sum of each row, which is a problem because `big.matrix` is column-oriented, so as far as I can tell all the summary functions are column oriented (e.g. `colsum`, `colmax`, etc.) and there is no function available by default for computing row sums. Of course I can do `apply(x, 1, sum)`, but this will take a very long time. I can also loop over the columns one by one and use vectorized addition to add them:

```
mysum <- rep(0, nrow(x))
for (i in seq(ncol(x))) 
  mysum <- mysum + x[,i]
```

but this still takes over 20 minutes, and is obviously suboptimal since it is creating a new 60-million-element vector each time through the loop. It seems like there must be some faster way to do this.

### Edit

I got this down to 10 minutes by processing chunks of a million or so rows at a time, and calling rowSums on those, and then concatenating the results. I'd still be interested to know if there is an optimized way to do this, though.

Comment: Does `rowSums` not work on it? Can you transpose and then take `colsum`?

Comment: Assuming you have `numeric` data, the time you indicate corresponds to a throughput of roughly 60 MB/s (72 GB data in 20 minutes = 3.6 GB per minute). Depending on where the data is stored, this may be very close to the physical limits. How long does it take to *read* that file (`time cp file > /dev/null`)?

Comment: It's not R's numeric type. It's a `big.matrix` of integers, so I believe it is stored more compactly, both on disk and in memory. the on-disk file is around 30 GB, and I don't know if it loads the whole matrix into memory when I load it. You can't operate on the whole thing at once because it has more then `.Machine$integer.max` elements in it. That's why I have it in a `big.matrix`. You can't transpose a `big.matrix` quickly. Like I said, the data structure is column-oriented, so transposing it would have to completely rebuild the entire data structure.

Comment: You could always modify the code in the `Rcpp` gallery to do `rowSums` instead of `colSums`: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written some C++ code to do this, adapted from the [bigmemory Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/):

**rowSums.cpp**

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH, bigmemory)]]
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>

#include <numeric>

// Logic for BigRowSums.
template <typename T>
NumericVector BigRowSums(XPtr<BigMatrix> pMat, MatrixAccessor<T> mat) {
    NumericVector rowSums(pMat->nrow(), 0.0);
    NumericVector value(1);
    for (int jj = 0; jj < pMat->ncol(); jj++) {
      for (int ii = 0; ii < pMat->nrow(); ii++) {
        value = mat[jj][ii];
        if (all(!is_na(value))) {
          rowSums[ii] += value[0];
        }   
      }   
    }   
    return rowSums;
}

// Dispatch function for BigRowSums
//
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector BigRowSums(SEXP pBigMat) {
    XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);

    switch(xpMat->matrix_type()) {
      case 1:
        return BigRowSums(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<char>(*xpMat));
      case 2:
        return BigRowSums(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<short>(*xpMat));
      case 4:
        return BigRowSums(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<int>(*xpMat));
      case 6:
        return BigRowSums(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<float>(*xpMat));
      case 8:
        return BigRowSums(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<double>(*xpMat));
      default:
        throw Rcpp::exception("unknown type detected for big.matrix object!");
    }   
}
```

**In R:**

```
library(bigmemory)
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("rowSums.cpp")

m <- as.big.matrix(matrix(1:9, 3))
BigRowSums(m@address)
[1] 12 15 18
```

Comment: This looks great. If it's faster than what I've already got (it probably is) I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: I did try to create a filebacked big matrix to test it, but it ground my computer to a halt (the creation of it), so I killed it. I would be interested to see how it fares!

Comment: Can you not use Eigen or Armadillo? I don't think doing nested loops like that is gonna be very fast even in C++ ...